# Error in trigger statements in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute following statements in a mysql trigger (through phpmyadmin)

```
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE from balancetable WHERE triggeredby="salesinvoices" AND invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber;

INSERT INTO balancetable SET invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber,ledgerId=NEW.buyerId,date=NEW.invoiceDate,company=NEW.companyId,type="debit",triggeredby="salesinvoices";
END;
```

I am getting this error:

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE from balancetable WHERE triggeredby="salesinvoices" A' at line 1
```

I have been banging my head on this from last hour. Point out my stupidity pls :)

[image]

Comment: Since you have found a solution to your question post it as an answer so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your trigger and define when it should be fired:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `some_name` AFTER UPDATE ON `salesinvoices`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE from balancetable 
    WHERE triggeredby="salesinvoices" 
    AND invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber;

    INSERT INTO balancetable SET        
          invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber,
          ledgerId=NEW.buyerId,
          date=NEW.invoiceDate,
          company=NEW.companyId,
          type="debit",
          triggeredby="salesinvoices";
END;
| 
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I am doing it though phpmyadmin.

Comment: adding a trigger through phpmyadmin on a table. see the screenshot i just attached.

Comment: I am not familiar with PHPAdmin but I guess you can leave the `FOR EACH ROW BEGIN` in that wizard and just put in your other code.

Comment: i tried that. it doesn't work. It gives me following error: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO balancetable SET invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber,ledgerId=NEW.buyerI' at line 2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31028/discussion-between-benerd-and-juergen-d)

Comment: Actually I have no idea why this should fail. Sorry.

Comment: i don't have the console access. Just to phpmyadmin :(

Comment: You can execute queries with phpadmin. See [here](http://community.mybb.com/thread-4720.html)

Comment: hey i found the solution. Correct code is: BEGIN
    DELETE from balancetable 
    WHERE triggeredby="salesinvoices" 
    AND invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber;

    INSERT INTO balancetable SET        
          invoiceNumber=NEW.invoiceNumber,
          ledgerId=NEW.buyerId,
          date=NEW.invoiceDate,
          company=NEW.companyId,
          type="debit",
          triggeredby="salesinvoices";
END